# VS2010, DirectX and Intellisense troubles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, directx, intellisense

I have both VS2010 and VS2012 installed, but only in VS2012 highlighting and auto-complete seems to work correctly. At the same time Intellisense seems to work on VS2010, but not for DirectX... Here's an example:

VS2012 - all well. Also note how all the Windows/DirectX types are highlighted.

[image: VS2012]

---

VS2010 - no highlighting, no auto-completion.

[image: VS2010]

---

VS2010 - but here we can see that IntelliSense actually works, just kind of selectively.

[image: VS2010-2]

---

I have to use VS2010 so I need that problem fixed. I'm kind of new to Visual Studio so it may be something obvious I'm missing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There should be project templates, IIRC...

Comment: Ok, I've figured out that part by now (there are no templates for DirectX though), so I removed that part of the question. Still no luck with IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about the IntelliSense in VS2010 in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The [Complete Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1thxcsd9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option is also available:

"To open the completion list, type the first few letters of the name, or press ALT+RIGHT ARROW or CTRL+SPACEBAR."

You should also be aware of [When IntelliSense Is Unavailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Make sure you specified include directories for DirectX headers in the project's options correctly. Rebuilding the solution also helps sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped. However I can't seem to find an option to display auto-complete automatcally (e.g. after typing three letters) which happens in VS2012. I assume VS2012 just has some improvements for IntelliSense? Do you know how to enable highlighting of Windows/DX defined types and constants in VS2010?

Comment: Auto-complete doesn't show up automatically in my case neither. Sorry, I don't know how to enable highlighting of defined types and names, I think it's unavailable in VS2010.